# Interactively Manipulate SparseArrays or Lists

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, sparse-arrays, interactive

I'd love to use `SparseArray`or `List` to group a set of parameters together in a function.

```
params[a] = 5;
params[b] = 6;

AFunction[p_] := p[a] * p[b]
```

If I however want to create a manipulatable entry in the array, it doesn't work:

```
Manipulate[params[c], {params[c], 0, 50}]
Manipulate::vsform: "Manipulate argument {params[c],0,50} does not have the correct form for a variable specification."
```

The same thing for a "normal" value works as intended:

```
Manipulate[c, {c, 0, 50}]
```

The Mathematica 10.0 documentation states, that [Manipulate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) should be able to interactively transform any expression.

I also tried it with `With`, which leads to the same error.

Is this straight not possible, or am I doing something wrong. How do you handle big manipulatable parameter sets?

Comment: `{params[c], 0, 50}` here `param[c]` is not a control variable. This sould be a symbol, like x, c, y, etc.. not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functions:

```
params[a] = 5;
params[b] = 6;
Manipulate[params[a] = n, {n, 10, 100, 1}]
```

In contrast:

```
c = 1;
Manipulate[c, {c, 10, 100, 1}]
```

Here, the `Manipulate` displays the change of the local `c`. It doesn't change the global `c` which still has value `1`.

Comment: Tank you very much, that absolutely makes sense! Great Answer!

Comment: Btw. I'm using Mathematica 10`s assosiactions now, although they also need to be substituted away.